# How can I set multiple roles in the keycloak.protect()?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I'm using keycloak.protect('user') in nodejs (keycloak-connect lib) for my APIs to allow only user role and it works.

How could I add multiple roles in the keycloak.protect()?
I tried with the keycloak.protect(['user','admin']) but it allows anyone with a valid token (it looks like to have the same behavior of keycloak.protect())

Comment: Probably I found the workaround by using a function (instead of string):

Comment: function test(token, request){ return token.hasRole('user') || token.hasRole('admin'); }

Comment: router.get('/api/:service', keycloak.protect(test), function (req, res) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

In fact, inside Keycloak Realms, your users 'admin' may also have a 'user'  rule.
That way, all 'user' can access this route (including 'admin/user').